# Xamarin web api and other platforms time problems

Tags: .net, xamarin, token, webapi

i created an api by .NET, webform and xamarin mobile.. when i check token expire time i saw different times but all of them are workin same computer. what is the problem and how can i solve these problem.
When i check with Fidler i saw time which is .issued=Sun, 24 May 2020 20:38:34 GMT and my computer time is 23:58 how it can be.. both of them are running  on same compuer
[WEB API Time on Computer and Computer Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoUzc.png)

```
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new 
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            Provider = new Saglayici() // 
        };
```

Comment: where is the code you used to create the token?  Your previous question was closed because of a lack of detail and clarity, and this question has the same problem.

Comment: Token Created :
OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthAuthorizationServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new Microsoft.Owin.PathString("/token"), 
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                Provider = new Saglayici() /
            };